# Why handleClick event is not fired from Child Element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass `onClick` event to Child component, but nothing is being fired. What I'm trying to do is to pass `data-id` and value of each input to update the value for each child component. But I can't get it to work.

Here's the fiddle. When I clicked the button there's nothing being fired.

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/knh8r55f/1/

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
  var Assets = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return { data: [{ name : 'Initialising...' }] };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {

     if(this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState({data : [
            {
                'embed_code': 'embed_code1',
                'name': 'cat1'
            },
            {
                'embed_code': 'embed_code2',
                'name': 'cat2'
            }
        ]});
      }

    },

    handleClick : function(event) {
      console.log('asdf');
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.data.map(function(result, index) {
            return (
              <Asset data={result} onButtonClicked={this.handleClick}/>
            );
          })}
        </div>);
    }
  });

  var Asset = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div key={this.props.data.embed_code}>
          <div>{this.props.data.name}</div>
          <span>Category</span>
          <input name="category" data-id={this.props.data.embed_code} />
          <input type="button" onClick={this.props.onButtonClicked} value="Update!"/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  React.renderComponent(
    <Assets>, document.body
  );
```

Not sure if i'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `.map` callback, `this` refers to the **global object**, not the `Assets` instance. `this.handleClick` tries to access the *global variable* `handleClick`, which probably doesn't exist. Thus you are passing `undefined` to `onButtonClicked`, which is the same as not passing the prop at all.

You can pass a second argument to `.map`, which will become the value of `this` inside the callback:

```
{this.state.data.map(function(result, index) {
    return (
        <Asset data={result} onButtonClicked={this.handleClick}/>
    );
}, this)} // <- pass instance as second argument
```

For more information, have a look at the [**`map` documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Thanks very much I missed that!